# How to run a function automatically on scheduled Intervals?

Tags: wordpress, cron, wordpress-hook

I am developing a plugin for a Wordpress website in which I would like to generate a report on the first day of every month and send it to the users/admin.

Creating a Cron job in the server would be a perfect solution but there are few hurdles in creating Cron Job programmatically as the procedure differs from Server to the server(I guess). 
So I am thinking of a WordPress function instead of creating a Cron Job in the server that does this job.

Do let me know if you guys have any idea about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution myself. I hope it would be helpful for others.

```
function do_this_in_an_hour() {

 $postid = "1"; //Supply post-Id here $post->ID.
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID'    =>  $postid,
        'post_status'   =>  'draft'
        ));     
}
add_action( 'my_new_event','do_this_in_an_hour' );

wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 7200, 'my_new_event' );

// time() + 7200 = two hour from now.
```

Comment: This is not really a solution and this is more of a workaround. This will run only when WordPress is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

They will only run when WordPress is loaded, if the interval time has passed

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' );
function isa_add_every_three_minutes( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 60,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 1 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}

// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' );
}

// Hook into that action that'll fire every three minutes
add_action( 'isa_add_every_three_minutes', 'every_three_minutes_event_func' );
function every_three_minutes_event_func() {
    $content = "some text here";
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpressrootfolder/".time()."-myText.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Both these answers are similar whereas I would like the function to run even if the website is not loaded. Is there any other way we could achieve this without using Server Cron Jobs?

Comment: wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1  cron task set in your server

Comment: Since configuring Cron job differs from server to server, I would like to automate a function without using Server Cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Set cron schedules time in second.

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'cron_schedules'  );
public function cron_schedules( $schedules ) {

        $schedules['monthly'] = array(
            'interval' => 2635200,
            'display'  => __( 'Once a month' , 'text-domain'),
        );

        return $schedules;
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'init_cron_job' );
    function init_cron_job() {
      $hook = 'domain_send_email_reporting';
      $schedule = wp_get_schedule( $hook );
             $frequency="monthly";
            // If settings changed clear previous hook
            if ( $schedule != $frequency ) {
                wp_clear_scheduled_hook( $hook );
            }

            // Add hook event
            if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( $hook ) ) {
                wp_schedule_event( time(), $frequency, $hook );
            }
     }
    add_action( 'domain_send_email_reporting', 'send_email_reporting' ] 
    );
    function domain_send_email_reporting(){
    $email="";
    $subject="";
    $message="";
    $headers="";
    wp_mail( $email, $subject, $message, $headers );
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).